# DIV elements overlapping each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make multiple divs go next to each other (on the same line) but they keep overlapping each other.

I've tried solving this issue with `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` but the divs overlap each other instead of going next to each other on the same line.

(I used tachyons css toolkit)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.10.0/css/tachyons.min.css"/>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="guesses" class="br3 tc">
            <div class="colors">
                <div class="br-100 yellow"></div>
                <div class="br-100 orange"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#guesses {
    width: 512px;
    height: 512px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 16px;
}
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 16px;
}
```

I expect the divs to be spread across the `colors` div in an equal way and that doesn't overflow.

Comment: There's zero JavaScript in your script

Comment: Sorry, that's HTML, I'll fix that.

Comment: Change the yellow and orange clases to be position: relative instead of absolute

Comment: Get rid of the `position: absolute`.

Comment: I changed `position: absolute` to `position: relative` and added `display: inline-block` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: `position: relative` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to remove the `position: absolute` and then using `display: inline-block` does the trick no problem.

<kbd>[**Working example**](https://jsbin.com/mijaratifa/)</kbd>

```
.orange,
.yellow {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Perhaps you were applying this CSS rule somewhere else in your attempts? Or perhaps keeping your `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using CSS property - `display: flex;`

You need to remove the position too.

Here is the working code:

https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/XWWzZzW

Answer (score 0):

```css
#guesses {
    width: 512px;
    height: 512px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div id="guesses" class="br3 tc">
            <div class="colors">
                <div class="br-100 yellow"></div>
                <div class="br-100 orange"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using `display: flex` on the parent and `display: inline-flex` on the children. Also, adding `justify-content: center` will center the children for you. I added an additional class to your colors, so that we can reutilize it. Hope it helps!

```css
#guesses {
    width: 512px;
    height: 512px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.color {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
.orange {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="guesses" class="br3 tc">
            <div class="colors">
                <div class="br-100 yellow color"></div>
                <div class="br-100 orange color"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```